# How to get the message of the Bad request in API response with openAPI generated controllers in gradle spring

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, openapi, openapi-generator

I have a Spring boot application (2.6.9) with gradle 7.6.

I'm using the open api generator gradle plugin to generate request controllers in my application, with the delegate pattern.

```
    id 'org.openapi.generator' version '6.3.0'
```

Here are my open api generate config options,

```
        "dateLibrary": "java8",
        "hideGenerationTimestamp": "true",
        "delegatePattern": "true",
        "library": "spring-boot",
        "serializableModel": "true",
        "useBeanValidation": "true",
        "useTags": "true",
        "implicitHeaders": "true",
        "openApiNullable": "false"
```

In the open API specification, I have an endpoint with a required parameter.

```
/resource/getByDate:
  get:
    tags:
      - resource
    summary: summary
    description: desc
    operationId: operation
    parameters:
      - name: fromDate
        in: query
        description: date
        required: true
        schema:
          type: string
```

Module compiles successfully and initializes as expected. Once a request is sent without the required 'fromDate' parameter the response is,

```
"timestamp": "2023-03-02T13:59:52.112+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"path": "/resource/getByDate"
```

In the application logs the following message is logged,

```
 Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'fromDate' for method parameter type String is not present
```

How to include this message in the response body with the code generator support?

Comment: See if this could be of  help : https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/examples/v3.0/api-with-examples.yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of your responses, include a response for a 400 status.  Something like this:

```yaml
  /resource/getByDate:
    get:
      tags:
        - resource
      summary: summary
      description: desc
      operationId: operation
      parameters:
        - name: fromDate
          in: query
          description: date
          required: true
          schema:
            type: string
      responses:
        '400':
          description: Invalid Request
          headers:
            x-whatever:
              description: If you want to include headers in your response
              schema:
                type: string
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                properties: 
                  title:
                    type: string
                  message:
                    type: string
                  statusCode:
                    type: string
                  method:
                    type: string
```

This will generate a class that looks something similar to this:

```java
public class Operation400Response implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonProperty("title")
  private String title;

  @JsonProperty("message")
  private String message;

  @JsonProperty("statusCode")
  private String statusCode;

  @JsonProperty("method")
  private String method;
```

Now you can create a `ControllerAdvice` class to handle the `MissingServletRequestParameterException` like this:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler
{
  @Override
  public ResponseEntity<Operation400Response> handleMissingServletRequestParameter(MissingServletRequestParameterException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request)
  {
    var response = new Operation400Response().title("Missing required parameter").message(ex.getMessage()).statusCode(status);
    return new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging the ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. It seems so useful.